# Django/Python/toDataURL return a response with the string from toDataURL

Tags: javascript, python, django, image, todataurl

I have saved in a database a string return by the javascript method toDataURL. An exemple is available here: http://pastebin.com/0Qu8rngD

I need to return the image in a django response. Something like:

```
return HttpResponse(image, mimetype='image/png')
```

I have tried many methods with base64decode, urlsafe_b64decode, Image ... with no success. The navigator does not display the image, it can't read the response data.

Of course I can display my image in a HTML page with `<img src="{{image}}">`, it works well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image is base64 encoded in the data uri; decode the image first:

```
import base64

...    

data_uri = 'data:...'
image_data = data_uri.partition('base64,')[2]
binary = base64.b64decode(image_data)
return HttpResponse(binary, mimetype='image/png')
```

Comment: Instead of importing `base64`, we could use shorter `image_data.decode('base64')`. Anyway, +1 for being faster =)

Comment: Thank you, it's perfect, partition() is the solution !

Comment: Sure.. Just hope I have another +1 slot.